# Why does AmCharts export change color to black and white?

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts

I am using AmCharts and everything is working perfect except for **Export**.

I am using the following libraries for AmCharts:

```
<link href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Content/amcharts_3.20.9.free/amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/amcharts_3.20.9.free/amcharts/serial.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/amcharts_3.20.9.free/amcharts/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.js"></script>
```

and inside `AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", {` I am using:

```
"export": {
        "enabled": true
    }`
```

My chart is colorful like this by default:

[image: Colorful Chart]

But after I download to PDF, PNG, JPG etc or click `Annotate...` menu option the chart turns to Black and White (Grayscale) like this image:

[image: Greyscaled Chart]

[Here is video of this issue reproduced](https://db.tt/2nGTHlYO).

```js
var chartData = generateChartData();

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", {
        
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",
        "legend": {
            "useGraphSettings": true
        },
        "dataProvider": chartData,
        "valueAxes": [{
            "id": "HeartRate",
            "axisColor": "Green",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "position": "left",
            "offset": 50,
        }, {
            "id": "BloodPressure",
            "axisColor": "Purple",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "position": "left"
        }, {
            "id": "Temperature",
            "axisColor": "Black",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "offset": 0,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "position": "right"
        },
        {
            "id": "RespiratoryRate",
            "axisColor": "Gold",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "offset": 50,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "position": "right"
        },
        {
            "id": "Weight",
            "axisColor": "Orange",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "offset": 100,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "position": "right"
        },
        {
            "id": "Age",
            "axisColor": "LightSeaGreen",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "offset": 150,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "position": "right"
        }],
        "graphs": [{
            "valueAxis": "BloodPressure",
            "lineColor": "Purple",
            "bullet": "triangleUp",
            "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
            "hideBulletsCount": 30,
            "title": "BloodPressureSystolic",
            "valueField": "BloodPressureSystolic",
            "fillAlphas": 0
        },
        {
            "valueAxis": "BloodPressure",
            "lineColor": "MediumPurple",
            "bullet": "triangleDown",
            "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
            "hideBulletsCount": 30,
            "title": "BloodPressureDiastolic",
            "valueField": "BloodPressureDiastolic",
            "fillAlphas": 0
        }, {
            "valueAxis": "HeartRate",
            "lineColor": "Green",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
            "hideBulletsCount": 30,
            "title": "Pulse",
            "valueField": "Pulse",
            "fillAlphas": 0
        },
        {
            "valueAxis": "Temperature",
            "lineColor": "Black",
            "bullet": "bubble",
            "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
            "hideBulletsCount": 30,
            "title": "Temperature",
            "valueField": "Temperature",
            "fillAlphas": 0
        },
        {
            "valueAxis": "RespiratoryRate",
            "lineColor": "Gold",
            "bullet": "square",
            "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
            "hideBulletsCount": 30,
            "title": "RespiratoryRate",
            "valueField": "RespiratoryRate",
            "fillAlphas": 0
        },
        {
            "valueAxis": "Weight",
            "lineColor": "Orange",
            "bullet": "diamond",
            "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
            "hideBulletsCount": 30,
            "title": "Weight",
            "valueField": "Weight",
            "fillAlphas": 0
        },
        {
            "valueAxis": "Age",
            "lineColor": "LightSeaGreen",
            "bullet": "diamond",
            "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
            "hideBulletsCount": 30,
            "title": "Age",
            "valueField": "Age",
            "fillAlphas": 0
        }],
        "chartScrollbar": {},
        "chartCursor": {
            "cursorPosition": "mouse",
            "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
            "valueLineEnabled": true
        },
        "categoryField": "RecordedDate",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "parseDates": true,
            "axisColor": "#DADADA",
            "minorGridEnabled": true
        },
        "export": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    });

    chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
    zoomChart();

    // generate some random data, quite different range
    function generateChartData() {
        var chartData = [];
        var firstDate = new Date();
        firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 100);


        chartData=[
            //date: newDate,
            //visits: visits,
            //hits: hits,
            //views: views
                
                    {
                        "RecordedDate": moment("26/07/2016 00:00:00", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate(),
                        "Temperature": 98,
                        "Pulse": 100,
                        "BloodPressureSystolic": 120,
                        "BloodPressureDiastolic": 98,
                        "RespiratoryRate": 15,
                        "Weight": 50,
                        "Age": 18
                        },
                
                
                    {
                        "RecordedDate": moment("27/07/2016 00:00:00", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate(),
                        "Temperature": 99.4,
                        "Pulse": 101,
                        "BloodPressureSystolic": 110,
                        "BloodPressureDiastolic": 112,
                        "RespiratoryRate": 98,
                        "Weight": 60,
                        "Age": 19
                        },
                
                
                    {
                        "RecordedDate": moment("28/07/2016 00:00:00", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate(),
                        "Temperature": 100,
                        "Pulse": 102,
                        "BloodPressureSystolic": 109,
                        "BloodPressureDiastolic": 95,
                        "RespiratoryRate": 97,
                        "Weight": 66,
                        "Age": 20
                        }
                
        ]

        return chartData;
    }

    function zoomChart() {
        chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 20, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
    }
```

```css
#chartdiv2 {
    width   : 100%;
    height  : 500px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
```

And [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alijamal14/6w4wkqgs/3/) of the issue.

I have test this behavior in both Google's Chrome and Mozilla's Firefox
Please guide me how can I modify this question to make it more understandable? I have searched a lot but could not find similar issue on the web. I would really appreciate if [amcharts.com](http://amcharts.com) Support also participates in helping out.

Comment: If it possible please provide an example on https://jsfiddle.net/ or similar service.

Comment: My Code is writen in ASP.Net MVC and some razor is included can jsfiddle will understand my code?

Comment: I making a JSFiddle from the code generated in browser I will be back with the code in a while kindly wait, Thank You

Comment: @AndreyEtumyan I have tried to create a JSFiddle but its not working can you help me with this, Thank You https://jsfiddle.net/alijamal14/6w4wkqgs/1/

Comment: Just make a blank fiddle and add your JavaScript code, where you configure your chart. Don't bother if it doesn't work. We just need to take a look at your code.

Comment: Thank You @gerric jsfiddle.net/alijamal14/6w4wkqgs/1 gerric Here code my browser created but its not working in JSFiddle I am also trying to making another JsFiddle of Original Code

Comment: @AndreyEtumyan And gerric I have update my JSFiddel this is the issue kindly please look Thank You https://jsfiddle.net/alijamal14/6w4wkqgs/3/

Comment: This seems to be bug with the export plugin. It looks like the colors aren't recognized properly. If you change all colors to lower case the "standard" colors (like e.g. orange) work. You can fix this using HEX color codes by now.

Comment: No problem. I actually opened an [Issue](https://github.com/amcharts/export/issues/40) on GitHub for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @gerric Suggested

> This seems to be bug with the export plugin. It looks like the colors aren't recognized properly. If you change all colors to lower case the "standard" colors (like e.g. orange) work. You can fix this using HEX color codes by now.

I tried to change color names `Green` to `green` few of the color worked

Then I tried HEX as mentioned below and its working

```js
var chartData = generateChartData();

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", {

  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "legend": {
    "useGraphSettings": true
  },
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "HeartRate",
    "axisColor": "#00ff00",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "left",
    "offset": 50,
  }, {
    "id": "BloodPressure",
    "axisColor": "#551a8b",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "left"
  }, {
    "id": "Temperature",
    "axisColor": "#000000",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "offset": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "right"
  }, {
    "id": "RespiratoryRate",
    "axisColor": "#ffd700",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "offset": 50,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "right"
  }, {
    "id": "Weight",
    "axisColor": "#ffa500",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "offset": 100,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "right"
  }, {
    "id": "Age",
    "axisColor": "#20b2aa",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "offset": 150,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "right"
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "valueAxis": "bloodpressure",
    "lineColor": "#551a8b",
    "bullet": "triangleUp",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "BloodPressureSystolic",
    "valueField": "BloodPressureSystolic",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "valueAxis": "BloodPressure",
    "lineColor": "#9370db",
    "bullet": "triangleDown",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "BloodPressureDiastolic",
    "valueField": "BloodPressureDiastolic",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "valueAxis": "HeartRate",
    "lineColor": "#00ff00",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "Pulse",
    "valueField": "Pulse",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "valueAxis": "Temperature",
    "lineColor": "#000000",
    "bullet": "bubble",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "Temperature",
    "valueField": "Temperature",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "valueAxis": "RespiratoryRate",
    "lineColor": "#ffd700",
    "bullet": "square",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "RespiratoryRate",
    "valueField": "RespiratoryRate",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "valueAxis": "Weight",
    "lineColor": "#ffa500",
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "Weight",
    "valueField": "Weight",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "valueAxis": "Age",
    "lineColor": "#20b2aa",
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "Age",
    "valueField": "Age",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }],
  "chartScrollbar": {},
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorPosition": "mouse",
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true
  },
  "categoryField": "RecordedDate",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "minorGridEnabled": true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});

chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
zoomChart();

// generate some random data, quite different range
function generateChartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 100);


  chartData = [
    //date: newDate,
    //visits: visits,
    //hits: hits,
    //views: views

    {
      "RecordedDate": moment("26/07/2016 00:00:00", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate(),
      "Temperature": 98,
      "Pulse": 100,
      "BloodPressureSystolic": 120,
      "BloodPressureDiastolic": 98,
      "RespiratoryRate": 15,
      "Weight": 50,
      "Age": 18
    },


    {
      "RecordedDate": moment("27/07/2016 00:00:00", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate(),
      "Temperature": 99.4,
      "Pulse": 101,
      "BloodPressureSystolic": 110,
      "BloodPressureDiastolic": 112,
      "RespiratoryRate": 98,
      "Weight": 60,
      "Age": 19
    },


    {
      "RecordedDate": moment("28/07/2016 00:00:00", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate(),
      "Temperature": 100,
      "Pulse": 102,
      "BloodPressureSystolic": 109,
      "BloodPressureDiastolic": 95,
      "RespiratoryRate": 97,
      "Weight": 66,
      "Age": 20
    }

  ]

  return chartData;
}

function zoomChart() {
  chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 20, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}
```

```css
#chartdiv2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
```

I just received message from amCharts support against my ticket according to him they are not supporting color names with default library but asked me to used hexidecimal colors here is message for detail

> Hi Ali,
>
> You need to use hexidecimal colors ("#ff0000")or rgb ("rgb(255, 0, 0)"
>   values for your colors. fabric.js, the underlying library used by the
>   export plugin, does not support named colors such as "Orange" and
>   "Black".
>
> Here's your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6w4wkqgs/5/
>
> Hope this helps.

Thank You everyone for helping sorting out the issue. You people are great.

Comment: I just received message from Anthony Piris from amCharts according to him they are not supporting color names but asked me to used hexidecimal colors
Hi Ali,

You need to use hexidecimal colors ("#ff0000")or rgb ("rgb(255, 0, 0)" values for your colors. fabric.js, the underlying library used by the export plugin, does not support named colors such as "Orange" and "Black".

Here's your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6w4wkqgs/5/

Hope this helps.

Best,

Anthony Piris
amCharts

Comment: It's a limitation from fabricjs which does not interpret all color names and returns "black" as a default. I suggest to use HEXadecimal or RGBA instead as mentioned above.